# Multilple files instead of one single extension.js file when using crossrider?

Tags: javascript, crossrider

I'd like to port my chrome extension using crossrider. I'd also like to maintain different extension js files instead of one gigantic extension.js file.

I am assuming I can add the extension js files as "Resources".

Is that correct?

Will js functions added to Resource files be automatically accessible within extension.js or do I need to clarify paths?

Or is there a manifest file I can access and modify to let crossrider know that I have multiple extension pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using resources, you can maintain files such as js, css, html, images, ... and include them as required. You can even maintain them in a folder structure that meet your needs. For more information, see [appAPI.resources](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.resources).

In your scenario to include a js resource file in your *extension.js* file, simply use [appAPI.resources.includeJS](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.resources-method-includeJS) and the code is immediately available thereafter in the extension.js file.

For example, if you have a resource file named *script.js* in a folder named *js*, you can include it as follows:

**extension.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  appAPI.resources.includeJS('js/script.js');
  writeToConsole('Hellow World');
});
```

**script.js** in folder **js**:

```
function writeToConsole(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}
```

Disclaimer: I am a Crossrider employee

Comment: @Shlomo, I've an extension with that working great. Now I want to organize my code in different files used at background scope, however I've seen in the docs that ´appAPI.resources.includeJS´ is not available at background. How can I do?

Comment: Currently, for the background scope we suggest trying the following which works in most cases: $.globalEval(appAPI.resources.get('js/script.js'));